# "Much though" vs "much as"

Tags: word-choice

> **Much though** he likes her, he doesn't love her.
>
> **Much as** he needed money for a new car, he decided not to borrow it from the bank.

Both are correct in a grammar book, but my teacher tells me that the first is wrong. Why?

Comment: *Much though* seems fine to me although probably less common than *much as*. Is your teacher a native speaker of English?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in meaning between the two forms, but note that in OP's usage, *much as* is effectively short for **as much as**.

To my mind, this implies *much though* is short for **as much though**, which is clearly nonsense. Consequently, I don't like the form one little bit, but I do note that it's used in the [The living age: Volume 87 (1865)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4Q8uAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA184&dq=%22much%20though%20he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=appoT_b-KYKq8APr8tGQCQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22much%20though%20he%22&f=false) - *"Much though he loved Stanford Rivers..."*

That's obviously not an isolated example, but it's worth noting the [relative frequency of occurrence](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much%20though%20it,much%20as%20it&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

That's *"much as it"*:8990K, *"much though it"*:104K - if it's "grammatical", it's not much favoured. It's also worth noting that within those results, *most* of the hits for *"as"* are actually for our context here, but most of the *"though"* instances aren't. I can't produce a chart for an unambiguous string of words because nothing occurs often enough, but ["but much though it"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20much%20as%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22but%20much%20though%20it%22&oq=%22but%20much%20though%20it%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3476l4939l1l5610l8l8l0l0l0l0l90l422l8l8l0&gs_l=serp.3...3476l4939l1l5610l8l8l0l0l0l0l90l422l8l8l0.frgbld.&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=83eff03ccb2cc236&biw=1290&bih=902) gets only 9 hits in Google Books, whereas ["but much as it"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20much%20as%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets 29,100.

Clearly the preference is **very** strong, so OP's teacher is correct in saying the usage is "wrong", even though strictly speaking it seems to be grammatical. In the final analysis, it's what people *actually* say/write that counts, not what they're *allowed* to say, but normally don't.

Comment: @Daniel: Quite. Thinking about it some more, I can't come up with any justification at all for saying it's *not* grammatical. I'm still minded to think my point about structural similarity to *as much as* would influence others as well, but that's no reason for ruling against *though* on **grammatical** grounds. I think it really is just "preference".